# The word "you" missing from Careers certification tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

If I go to my profile on Careers then "Add certification" and "Time frame" the tool tip says:

"When did achieve this certification...?"

[image]

Shouldn't it be:

"When did you achieve this certification...?"

Answer (score 3):

Yep.  It will be fixed in the next build cycle on 9/1/2012.  It looks like this change just missed this mornings release.